# Should I prune my Zucchini's flowers?

Tags: vegetables, pruning, squash

I have two very young zuchinnis that are starting to grow flowers, they barely have 4 or 5 little leaves so I think they're very small to allow them to have fruits. Should I prune the flowers?

[image: Flowers]

Answer (score 2):

Most likely these first flowers will all be male (carrying only pollen, but not able to form a fruit) so you won't need to worry about your tiny plants attempting to carry fruit.  I would not attempt to prune them at this point because it will be very difficult to cut off the tiny flower buds and not injure the main plant.  If it turns out that any of these buds are actually female flowers (those with a miniature fruit at the bottom of the petals) then you can cut them off when they are large enough to do so easily without damaging the rest of the plant.

Comment: I think some of them are female flowers... Thank you very much!